# Ionic 2 env variables

Tags: angular, ionic2, environment-variables

I want to have env variables in my Ionic app, based on the value set with `NODE_ENV` during build script. I created the following module:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export interface IEnv {
  apiBaseUrl?: string;
}

export let EnvService = new InjectionToken<IEnv>('env.variables');

declare const process: any;

@NgModule({})
export class EnvModule {
  static forVariables(envs: IEnv): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: EnvModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: EnvService,
        useFactory: (): IEnv => {
          switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
            case 'prod':
              return Object.assign({
                name: 'production'
              }, envs);
            case 'dev':
              return Object.assign({
                name: 'development'
              }, envs);
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Which I import into my Ionic 2 module:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    EnvModule.forVariables({
      apiBaseUrl: 'http:/...'
    })
  ]
})
```

This works fine unless I use the `prod` version of ionic build, so if I use `ionic-app-scripts build --prod` it will give the following error:

```
Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported
```

So I rewrote my module like this:

```
export function provideVariables(envs: IEnv) {
  switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case 'prod':
      return Object.assign({
        name: 'production'
      }, envs);
    case 'dev':
      return Object.assign({
        name: 'development'
      }, envs);
  }
}

@NgModule({})
export class EnvModule {
  static forVariables(envs: IEnv): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: EnvModule,
      providers: [{
        provide: EnvService,
        useFactory: provideVariables,
        deps: [envs]
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

But now I get a `No provider for [object Object]` error

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `envs` is an argument to `forVariables`. Angular won't let you do that.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I don't think that is true, they are doing it in the [angular router module](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L151)

Comment: sorry wrong line in the file: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L147

Comment: That says that the `RouterModule.forRoot` provides the value that is returned by calling `provideRoutes` passing `routes`, but that is not what I meant. I am talking about `deps: [envs]`. That is never provided directly. You are providing the result of calling `Object.assign` which is a different reference.

Comment: @AluanHaddad hum okay, so how do I make this work?

Comment: `@ngModule({providers: [{provide: EnvService, useValue: ? {name: process.env.NODE_ENV, apiBaseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? devUrl: prodUrl}]` or something like that. Depends on how the values are calculated.

Comment: @AluanHaddad well yes but the point here is to create a reusable module that will load variables, not to declare my variables within

Comment: Then use an ES Module. What makes an `ngModule` more appropriate? `export const envs = {name: process.env.NODE_ENV, apiBaseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? devUrl: prodUrl};`

Comment: I was thinking to use something like that in all my apps: `EnvModule.forVariables({apiBaseUrl: 'http:/...'})`

Comment: Sure, makes sense to me, but what does that have to do with a static method on an `ngModule` decorated class? I tend to think a class with only static methods is a very poor pattern as a simple object, or an exported value is simpler to work with, more regular, and is not coupled to the framework. Like a static method should be a factory or have something to do with instances, otherwise, why not just export a function?

Comment: I use this so that in every module on a single app, I can import `EnvModule` and I will get access to the `EnvService`, but maybe there is a simpler approach, I am not familiar enough with this to know what is best to use in my case. Could you share some code on how you will do it, knowing that I have many apps with lazy loaded modules within each and I don't want to repeat the same code 100 times